# How to sort a vector of strings in a specific predetermined order?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, sorting, vector

The problem: I need to sort a vector of strings in exact specific order. Let say we have a constant vector or a array with the exact order:

```
vector<string> correctOrder = {"Item3", "Item1", "Item5", "Item4", "Item2"};
```

Next, we have a dynamic incoming vector which will have same Items, but they maybe mixed and less in number.

```
vector<string> incommingVector = {"Item1", "Item5", "Item3"};
```

So I need to sort the `incomming` vector with the order like the first vector, `correctOrder`, and the result must be:

```
vector<string> sortedVector = {"Item3", "Item1", "Item5"};
```

I think the correct order may be represented in a different way, but can't figure out.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Using [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) for the actual sorting is a good start. I also suggest reading about [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to provide a custom comparison function that you pass to `std::sort` to use.

Comment: @gsamaras Maybe. Or maybe the OP wants to use the elements in the vector `correctOrder` to get the relative positions of the elements? I don't know, it's not really clear from the question.

Comment: This that is correct gsamaras. I need to sort relative to first vector.

Comment: I see that all of the answers are offline. Is there a more efficient online algorithm?

Comment: While all the answers tell you how you can solve in O(N * M log M), you can achieve this in O(log N * M log M) by using heaps, since they only take log N time for insertion. Note that it is not possible to lookup the values in the middle because then you would have to spend M time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own functor to sort your vector in template vector order as explained by below code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct MyComparator
{
    //static const int x = 9;
  const std::vector<std::string> correctOrder{"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"};
  bool operator() (const std::string& first,const std::string& second )
  {
      auto firstitr = std::find(correctOrder.begin(),correctOrder.end(),first);
      auto seconditr = std::find(correctOrder.begin(),correctOrder.end(),second);
      return firstitr < seconditr;
  }
};
void printVector(const std::vector<std::string>& input)
{
    for(const auto&elem:input)
    {
        std::cout<<elem<<" , ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
  std::vector<string> incomingVector = {"Item3", "Item5", "Item1"};
  std::cout<<"vector before sort... "<<std::endl;
  printVector(incomingVector);
  std::sort(incomingVector.begin(),incomingVector.end(),MyComparator());
  std::cout<<"vector after sort...."<<std::endl;
  printVector(incomingVector);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In my case there is exact 8 elements, and this solution works perfectly. Big Thanks !!

Answer (score 10):

If the default comparison is not enough (lexicographic comparison) then the simplest thing you can do is to provide the sort function with a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) that tells it which string come first.
You can have a [`unordered_map<string,int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) with the strings in your `correctorder` vector as keys and their corresponding position in the sorted array as values.

The `cmp` function will simply compare the values of the keys you provide in your `incommingVector`.

```
unordered_map<string, int> my_map;
for(int i = 0 ; i < correctorder.size() ; i++)
   my_map[correctorder[i]]=i;

auto cmp =[&my_map](const string& s, const string& s1){
   return my_map[s] < my_map[s1];
}   

sort(incommingVector.begin(), incommingVector.end() , cmp);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of [`std::unordered_map<std::string, int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), i.e., a hash table for *mapping a string into an integer* in constant time. You can use it for finding out the position that a given string occupies in your vector `correctOrder` in `O(1)`, so that you can compare two strings that are in the vector `incomming` in constant time.

Consider the following function `sort_incomming_vector()`:

```
#include <unordered_map>

using Vector = std::vector<std::string>;

void sort_incomming_vector(const Vector& correctOrder /*N*/, Vector& incomming /*M*/)
{
   std::unordered_map<std::string, int> order;

   // populate the order hash table in O(N) time
   for (size_t i = 0; i < correctOrder.size(); ++i)
      order[correctOrder[i]] = i;

   // sort "incomming" in O(M*log M) time
   std::sort(incomming.begin(), incomming.end(),
            [&order](const auto& a, const auto& b) { // sorting criterion
               return order[a] < order[b];
            }
   ); 
}
```

The hash table `order` *maps* the strings into integers, and this resulting integer is used by the lambda (i.e., the sorting criterion) passed to the sorting algorithm, [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), to compare a pair strings in the vector `incomming`, so that the sorting algorithm can permute them accordingly.

If `correctOder` contains `N` elements, and `incomming` contains `M` elements, then the hash table can be initialised in `O(N)` time, and `incomming` can be sorted in `O(M*log M)` time. Therefore, the whole algorithm will run in `O(N + M*log M)` time.

If `N` is much larger than `M`, this solution is optimal, since the dominant term will be `N`, i.e., `O(N + M*log M)` ~ `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a comparison function that returns the correct ordering and pass that to [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). To do that, you can write a reusable function that returns a lambda that compares the result of trying to [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) the two elements being compared. `std::find` returns iterators, and you can compare those with the `<` operator.

```
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> correctOrder = {"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"};
// Could be just std::string correctOrder[], or std::array<...> etc.

// Returns a sorter that orders elements based on the order given by the iterator pair
// (so it supports not just std::vector<string> but other containers too.
template <typename ReferenceIter>
auto ordered_sorter(ReferenceIter ref_begin, ReferenceIter ref_end) {
    // Note: you can build an std::unordered_map<ReferenceIter::value_type, std::size_t> to
    // be more efficient and compare map.find(left)->second with 
    // map.find(right)->second (after you make sure the find does not return a
    // one-past-the-end iterator.
    return [&](const auto& left, const auto& right) {
        return std::find(ref_begin, ref_end, left) < std::find(ref_begin, ref_end, right);
    };
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    vector<string> v{"Item3", "Item5", "Item1"};

    // Pass the ordered_sorter to std::sort
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), ordered_sorter(std::begin(correctOrder), std::end(correctOrder)));
    for (const auto& s : v)
        std::cout << s << ", "; // "Item1, Item3, Item5, "
}
```

Note that this answer less efficient with a large number of elements, but more simpler than the solutions using an `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` for lookup, but a linear search is probably faster for small number of elements. Do your benchmarking if performance matters.

Answer (score -3):

Edit: If you don't want the default comparison to be used, then you need to pass as a third parameter your custom compare method, as shown in the example that exists in the linked reference.

Use [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) and you are done:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <string>       // std::string
using namespace std;

int main () {
  vector<string> incommingVector = {"Item3", "Item5", "Item1"};

  // using default comparison (operator <):
  std::sort (incommingVector.begin(), incommingVector.end());

  // print out content:
  std::cout << "incommingVector contains:";
  for (std::vector<string>::iterator it=incommingVector.begin(); it!=incommingVector.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> incommingVector contains: Item1 Item3 Item5

Comment: Okey But lets say the correct order is {"Item4", "Item1", "Item3", "Item2", "Item5"}; would be work like this?

Comment: @RosenKaradinev for that you would need to use a custom compare function, that you would pass as the third parameter of `std::sort()`. Please see the reference I linked to my answer for more.

Comment: I think you misread the question and OP didnt use the best example (for the example in the question a simple sort does it, but not in the general case)

Comment: Not an answer to the question

Comment: Thanks to @RosenKaradinev I now understand the question!